# I can't convert command line params to ydl_opts for youtube_dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I want to use youtube_dl inside a python code. In the command line I use this code: `"youtube-dl --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args "-ss 00:01:00.00 -to 00:02:00.00" -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc7I-i7sPrg""`

How I can convert this code to Python:

```
ydl_opts = {

}

with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Thnx for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ydl_opts = {
      'external_downloader': 'ffmpeg',
      'external_downloader_args': "-ss 00:01:00.00 -to 00:02:00.00",
      'format': 'best'
}

with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Python arguments listed [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312).